# id: 'not' with variable

Tags: entry, variable

i think the following code shows the problem:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries({ section: 'news', limit: 2, **id: not this_id** }) %}
```

the big one doesn't work in this way. Has anyone an idea?

The content of this_id is a number.

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be a string:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries({ section: 'news', limit: 2, id: 'not 42' }) %}
```

so concat your variable like so:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries({ section: 'news', limit: 2, id: 'not ' ~ this_id }) %}
```